# HTML Audio cant show

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

When I enter the location of the audio, it shows me the location of the project and then the location of the audio, which makes the audio not appear on the page

[image]

Comment: you have to add code not an image for proper solution .

Answer (score 0):

If you just mention  it will not appear. Try using audio controls instead of audio in line 128.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="C:\abc\xyz.mp3">
</audio>
```